# Referring to column that is created in previous step using QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

In my model I use the regular points tool. The input for the regular points tool is a shapefile for the extent and for the point spacing I would like to use a value that was calculated in a previous step. The value that the tool should use as point spacing is located in a column of a shapefile that has multiple columns.

How can I define this input?